# Asterisk: rewrite set Caller id if number is "number" and multiple conditions

Tags: asterisk

I need to rewrite a Caller id: this code seems to work
but I want to set it for a multiple condition(for example, if number is 1005 rewrite to 383838, if number is 1006 then rewrite to 848481, etc)
Anyone know how to do?

```
exten => _X.,1,Gotoif($[${CALLERID(num)}=1004]?2)
exten => _X.,2,SET(CALLERID(all)=My company<1234489>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use callerid matching in dialplan.

```
exten => _X./_1005,1,SET(CALLERID(all)=My company<1234489>)
exten => _X./_1006,1,SET(CALLERID(all)=My company<848481>)

exten => _X.,2,Noop(doing something for all)
```

See end of page:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Pattern+Matching